# How can I detect circles and their diameters using OpenCV in Python?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on a program where I should detect pores (circles and their diameters) using OpenCV. The program detects the contours but does not detect the pores. The input image is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unk5X.jpg)

The code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image_paths = ["image_with_contours2.jpg"]

for i, image_path in enumerate(image_paths):
    # Read the image
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)

    # Convert the image to grayscale
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Apply Gaussian blur to reduce noise
    img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (5, 5), 0)

    # Apply Hough Circle Transform to detect circles
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img_blur, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp=1, minDist=50, param1=50, param2=30, minRadius=10, maxRadius=100)

    # Draw detected circles on the original image
    if circles is not None:
        circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype(int)
        for (x, y, radius) in circles:
            cv2.circle(image, (x, y), radius, (0, 0, 255), 2)

    # Save the image with detected circles
    cv2.imwrite(f'image_with_circles{i}.jpg', image)

    # Print the number of circles detected
    num_circles = 0 if circles is None else len(circles)
    print(f"Number of circles detected in {image_path}: {num_circles}")
```

Even by changing the Hough Circle Transform parameters, the circles are drawn almost randomly. I will appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you post original image?

Comment: Yes, of course [original image](https://ibb.co/KjkLqT6)